# How do I check ground on incoming power

Tags: gfci, grounding, afci

I have a unique problem, three dual function breakers trip at the same time with a ground fault indication. This mainly happens while asleep or if it happens during the day, I'm of course at work. This started all of a sudden and the neighbor had an electrician at his place the morning it all started, coincidence?
The breakers are fed by the same hot leg. During one night I tried to troubleshoot it and the ground was present, if I plugged the breaker into the other hot line, the breaker would not trip. This leads me to think that I have an issue with the incoming hot leg leaking to ground, or I have a leak somewhere in my house of several leaks. The electric company guy came out, checked the voltage only and said I was good.
So now I need to know the proper method to check for a ground fault or current leak on a powered up line and dead line. I think for a dead line I just take a resistance from each line to neutral,  should be open line. And that includes the main power coming in.
I have moved the three dual function breakers to the other hot line and no more tripping but that isn't fixing the problem.
I am willing to accept advice but I do want to do this work myself. And I plan to buy a new CB for troubleshooting purposes but I have to order it.

Comment: A little bit of formatting would make this much easier to read. An extra press of the `<Enter>` key doesn't cost a lot

Answer (score 2):

> This leads me to think that I have an issue with the incoming hot leg leaking to ground

That can't be it. Your breakers cannot see leakage to ground that occurs upstream. Utility power going to ground is, as far as GFCIs are concerned, no different than any other power usage outside your house.

GFCIs monitor the power flowing through all the wires they monitor (hot/neutral for single-pole, hot/hot/neutral for two-pole) to verify that the currents all add up (i.e. that nothing load-side is taking some alternate route to ground, possibly through a human). A fault on the load side will not affect how much current is passing through the device - that depends entirely (and only) on what is happening on the load side.

How are you determining that the breakers are reporting a ground fault? Are you positive they're not saying arc fault? How close is this neighbor - is it another unit in a multi-family building on the same transformer, or are they miles away? It could be that after the neighbor had electrical work done, an arc is occurring on one of the legs in their wiring and the arc-fault detection function of your breakers is picking that up. Series arc detection is like radio receiver "listening" for the crackle of an arc with the monitored wires as the antenna. It's not possible to isolate the line and load side in this case - the "noise" can travel through all the connected wires and trip breakers on different circuits. Possibly even in a different home in this case.